# Custom text to enumerate items

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, alignment

I would like to know how one can create a list in which each item is enumerated with some custom text, like in the following picture.[image]

I'm not asking how can one construct a list in which every member is of the form (Sn), for n a natural number, but rather how to create a list in which we could determine each item with any customized expression. I have no clue how one could implement this without manual alignment and spacing, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Akerbeitz I do not exactly understand your question. Do you want all items to be enumerated with the same number? Do you want to modify the enumerate counter? Or what? Please include a `MWE`.

Comment: I have rewritten the whole question... please let me know if its still unclear what I am asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned

> how to create a list in which we could determine each item with any
> customized expression

I have used the optional argument if `\item` in order to manually determine the corrensponding label. I have also used  `enumitem` to make sure the label is bold:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text using the \lipsum command. Do not use in actual document.
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries]
\item[(S1)] \lipsum[1][1]
\item[(S2)] \lipsum[4] 
\item[xyz] \lipsum[2][3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```